# The 'd' in 'Httpd' stands for daemon?

Tags: apache

I am wondering how the name 'Httpd' comes from, specifically what the 'd' stands for. Is it 'daemon' like 'initd'?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Httpd ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably daemon since it is "designed to be run as a standalone daemon process" as per the apache website httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/httpd.html